# How to get combination of Nth line(specific line) and last but one line from text file in Linux?

Tags: linux, command-line

In a file, I have 100 lines. But I want 17th and last but one as 99th line from the file.
I need the command combinedly.

Answer (score 1):

Get the 17th line:

```
head -17 file | tail -1
```

Get the 99th line:

```
tail -2 file | head -1
```

Combine the commands with a semicolon:

```
head -17 file | tail -1 ; tail -2 file | head -1
```